# How can i add User reference (or user_ref) to existing users in Tinypass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing client ROR application where used tinypass.

Now, i registered users with User reference (or user_ref) as a email to tinypass so i can authenticate that users again into site for access.

Now, client already register some users without User reference (or user_ref) so we have a issue to get data of that users from tinypass. Because of it, we can not allow them users to access data.

Now, how can i add User reference (or user_ref) to tinypass existing users of them email so I can solve that issue. Any way to add User reference (or user_ref) through programming or tinypass account?